# converting a for loop to a std::for_each

Tags: c++, foreach

I've got this for loop:

```
    std::vector<itemPtr>::iterator it;
    for(it=items.begin(); it!=items.end(); ++it)
    {
        investigators.addToLeaderInventory(*it);
    }
```

I'd like to convert it to something like this:

```
std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), investigators.addToLeaderInventory);
```

However, that line doesn't compile.  g++ shows me this:

```
error: no matching function for call to
‘for_each(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item>*,
std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item>,  
std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item> > > >,  
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item>*,  
std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item>,   
std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item> > > >, <unresolved overloaded
function type>)’  
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:4194: note: candidates are: _Funct  
std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter =  
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item>*,   
std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item>,   
std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<yarl::item::Item> > > >, _Funct = void 
(yarl::party::Party::*)(yarl::itemPtr)]
```

Hard to read, to say the least.  I imagine the solution is pretty simple, but I can't figure out what g++ is complaining about.  The signature of `investigators.addToLeaderInventory()` is this:

```
void ClassName::addToLeaderInventory(itemPtr item);
```

which should work with a `for_each`, shouldn't it?  What should I change?

Comment: if you are willing to use boost, there is excellent foreach implementation, BOOST_FOREACH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`for_each` takes a callable entity of some kind.  In order to call a member function on another object, you need to use `mem_fun`, which wraps the member function so that it can be called like an ordinary function, then you need to bind it to the object instance on which it should be called using `bind1st`:

```
std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), 
    std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&ClassName::add), &investigators));
```

Another option is to use the more modern `bind`, which your implementation may provide in the `std` or `std::tr1` namespace (if it doesn't, you can use [the implementation from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html)):

```
using std::placeholders::_1;

std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), 
    std::bind(&ClassName::add, &investigators, _1);
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ can't bind an object and a method together into a single callable "function". You have to do the binding explicitly, either via a object with a custom `operator()`...

```
class AddToLeaderInventory {
public:
    AddToLeaderInventory(party::Party& party) : party_(party) { }

    void operator()(item::Item& i) { party_.addToLeaderInventory(i); }

private:
    party::Party& party_;
};
...
std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), AddToLeaderInventory(investigators));
```

...or using a library such as Boost.Bind.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lambdas then you could do

```
for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), 
         [&](const ItemPtr& it) {investigators.addToLeaderInventory(it);});
```